# Disable Material Ripple on Tablayout

Tags: android, android-styles

I am trying to remove the Material Ripple Effect on my TabLayout's Tabs.

I am wondering if it is possible to do this?

Any ideas please?

I have tried setting the stateListAnimator to null but it still does not work

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"/>
```

Answer (score 46):

**app:tabBackground** does not work in my case.

This is my solution:

```
tabLayout.setTabRippleColor(null);
```

Comment: Your answer should be elaborated a bit more https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Try to provide an improved description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: this answer worked for me - where you have your tabLayout in your fragment/activity you would call this. for example in kotlin - 

                  
            val tabLayout = view.my_tab_layout
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager)
            tabLayout.tabRippleColor = null

Comment: You also can use `<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
...
app:tabRippleColor="@null"` in your xml file

Answer (score 33):

Add this line to TabLayout in XML:
`app:tabRippleColor="@null"`

Answer (score 17):

Try to change the background, for example, use the transparent color of android.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    app:tabBackground = "@android:color/transparent"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Answer (score 8):

Just add @null to the `tabRippleColor` attribute

```
 <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabRippleColor="@null" />  -> here
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `app:tabRippleColor`

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
     android:id="@+id/tabs"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="48dp"
     app:tabRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
     app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Comment: Imo this reads a lot better than `@null` especially in xml.

Answer (score 2):

Clean code

```
tabLayout.setTabRippleColorResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```