# How to disable an animation when Tab is selected in TabLayout android

Tags: android, material-ui

The grey color appears for fraction of seconds when I touch on TabLayout. how to disable it?[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61877903/1419353

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gray color you see after clicking the TabLayout is a ripple color. You can disable that by setting `app:tabRippleColor="@null"` in your XML.

Here is the code

```
  <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:tabRippleColor="@null"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```